# JavaScript iCal Library

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, icalendar

I am trying to write an application that will use Ember to post to a Rails app with a Postgres database backend. The application has a front end that deals with users calendars and keeping track of recurrence of events so I thought it would be great to use the iCal format for keeping track of everything and doing exports. Is there a JavaScript library that would work for generating, parsing and exporting iCal formatted events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a NodeJS module called [`node-icalendar`](https://github.com/tritech/node-icalendar), which you can use in conjunction with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) (a tool that lets you use NodeJS modules in the browser) generate and parse iCalendar files in your front-end app.

I've used `node-icalendar` in my own NodeJS apps, without too much luck (that's not to say it won't work for you!). What I personally ended up doing was reading the [iCalendar spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) and formulating my own super bare-bones `.ical` file generator that exactly met my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to parse the icalendar file on the server with Rails? You could use something like [ri_cal](https://github.com/rubyredrick/ri_cal).